# How to disallow the ModelSerializer update method?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm building an API and there's a route that I don't want it to be available for updates.

I tried to override the ModelSerializer's update() method, but I'm having some problems with the nested relationship.

This is the serializer code. The `last_location` and the `inventory` are nested relationship.

```
class SurvivorSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    last_location = LocationSerializer(many=False)
    inventory = InventorySerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Survivor
        fields = '__all__'


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        return Response({"Error": "Not allowed"}, status=HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

When I try to update I get this message:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `last_location` on serializer `SurvivorSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Response` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Response' object has no attribute 'last_location'.
```

Comment: A `Serializer` must return an instance (or list of instances), it can't return a `Response`. That's what a view returns. You can return `None`.

Comment: So how can I disallow the update and return a error message properly? I did a workaround creating a permission but I don't think it's the best way.

Comment: Are you using routes? or view sets? or plain views?

Comment: I'm using viewsets

Comment: So it's the viewset update method you need to override.

Comment: Either override the `update()` method in your viewset or, as you seem to have done, override the `get_permissions()` method to disallow the @action 'update'.

Comment: I'll try now. Thanks.

Comment: It worked overriding the update in viewsets. Thank u all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `viewset` allow only your prefered http methods.

```
http_method_names = ['get', 'post']   # so there is not put or patch anymore.
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the update method from `Serializer` to `ViewSet`.

```
class SurvivorViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Survivor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SurvivorSerializer

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        return Response({"Error": "Not allowed"}, status=HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```